# How to iterate through an object with key and get the value

Tags: javascript, object

So I am not sure why I having such a difficult time with this, but I have an object I am trying to map over to get a value from it.

For example:

```
let obj = {
      "lyzjmpkvbtocygakcoxu": {
        "label": "Show Time",
        "hour": "12",
        "minute": "00",
        "period": "p.m.",
        "add_time": "enabled",
        "bdlmynfythqgyzrhruhw_add_date": "December 01, 2021",
        "bdlmynfythqgyzrhruhw_stock": ""
      },
      "eueuuzvkteliefbnwlii": {
        "label": "Show Time",
        "hour": "05",
        "minute": "00",
        "period": "p.m.",
        "add_time": "enabled",
        "brtmypzvuooqhvqugjbj_add_date": "December 02, 2021",
        "brtmypzvuooqhvqugjbj_stock": ""
      }
    }
```

I want to be able to get this:

```
December 01, 2021, December 02, 2021
```

I was able to do this to get the values and key for "add_time", however what I want is values for key containing the "..._add_date".

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(
          (acc, elem) => {
            acc[elem] = obj[elem].add_time;
            return acc;
          },
          {},
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could search through the keys and `.find` the one that matches the pattern...

```js
let obj = {
      "lyzjmpkvbtocygakcoxu": {
        "label": "Show Time",
        "hour": "12",
        "minute": "00",
        "period": "p.m.",
        "add_time": "enabled",
        "bdlmynfythqgyzrhruhw_add_date": "December 01, 2021",
        "bdlmynfythqgyzrhruhw_stock": ""
      },
      "eueuuzvkteliefbnwlii": {
        "label": "Show Time",
        "hour": "05",
        "minute": "00",
        "period": "p.m.",
        "add_time": "enabled",
        "brtmypzvuooqhvqugjbj_add_date": "December 02, 2021",
        "brtmypzvuooqhvqugjbj_stock": ""
      }
    }
const result = Object.values(obj)
  .map(val =>
    Object.entries(val)
      .find(([key]) => key.endsWith('_add_date'))
      [1]
  )
  .join(', ');
console.log(result);
```

But a much better approach would be to fix the upstream code so it doesn't create such a strange structure to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for .  I understand the object could be structured better, but unfortunately, this is the structure from the JSON response